# Access Debian repo in Docker build: `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available`

Tags: debian, docker

When I try to build the following Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN set -eux; \
    apt update; \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates;

RUN set -eux; \
    echo "deb https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ bullseye nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list;

RUN set -eux; \
    apt update;
```

I get the error:

```
#0 1.077 Err:4 https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian bullseye InRelease
#0 1.077   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ABF5BD827BD9BF62
#0 1.082 Reading package lists...
#0 1.348 W: GPG error: https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ABF5BD827BD9BF62
#0 1.348 E: The repository 'https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
```

Is there a reasonably simple way to get access to the nginx package repository in a Docker build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the nginx repository as a "trusted" repository:

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN set -eux; \
    apt update; \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates;

RUN set -eux; \
    echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ bullseye nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list;

RUN set -eux; \
    apt update;
```

Configuring a repository as "trusted" means that GPG checks are not required.

Comment: wow, thank you so much! That works!! The other answers I found via searches were very complicated.